# How to make only part of Ember route model a promise?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I have a simple `template.hbs` like this:

```
// template.hbs

<p>{{model.x}}</p>
<p>{{model.y}}</p>
```

The following route.js works as expected:

```
// route.js

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({

    model() {

        return {
            x: 'foo',
            y: 'bar'
        };

    }
});

// output, immediately:
// foo
// bar
```

The following also works, now using a promise for the whole model:

```
// route.js

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';

export default Route.extend({

    model() {

        return new RSVP.Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve({
                    x: 'foo',
                    y: 'bar'
                });
            }, 1000);
        });

    }
});

// output, after 1s:
// foo
// bar
```

The following, where I want to make only `model.x` a promise - does NOT work.

```
// route.js

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';

export default Route.extend({

    model() {

        return {
            x: new RSVP.Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve('foo');
                }, 1000);
            }),
            y: 'bar'
        };

    }
});

// output, IMMEDIATELY:
// [object Object]
// bar
```

It renders output immediately, but after it enters the callback in `setTimeout` it doesn't change the rendered value for `model.x`.

I am aware of `RSVP.hash()`, but that will reject if any of the promises rejects. Is it possible to have independent promises for different parts of route model or only all-or-nothing?

Oddly enough, if the promise in question is returned by ember-data, e.g. `x: this.get('store').findRecord('user')`, it works as it should work (changing `template.hbs` with `<p>{{model.x.name}}</p>` for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [PromiseObject](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.PromiseObject) or [PromiseArray](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.PromiseArray) from ember-data:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
        return {
            x: DS.PromiseObject.create({
              promise: new RSVP.Promise((resolve) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                      resolve({name: 'foo'});
                  }, 5000);
              })
            }),
            y: 'bar'
        };
    }
});
```

For this to work, your promise result has to be an object (i.e. `{name: 'foo'}` instead of only `foo`). You can then use `x.name`in your template, which will return undefined until the promise returns.

Comment: Bullseye! Thank you, @Enno!

Answer (score 0):

In the last case,

`model.x` is Promise object, if you do `{{log model.x}}` in hbs, you can see it in console. You can try access the value using `{{model.x._result}}`. but this is not right way to do it.

In your case, you can try implementing setupController hook of the route,

```
setupController(controller,model)
  {
    this._super(...arguments);
    let xPromise = new RSVP.Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve('foo');
                }, 1000);
            });
    xPromise.then((result) =>{
      this.set('model.x',result);
    });

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I am looking for a way to leverage promises directly from the model hook. This solves the problem, but it looks like hacking as well.